# Как компилировать .proto файлы на линуксе?

Tags: c++, linux, gprs

Я скачал библиотеку grpc и утилиту proto c репозитория ubuntu. Как мне скомпилировать мой .proto файл??
Я нашел эту команду protoc -I ../../protos --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_cpp_plugin` habr.proto, но я не знаю путь к директиве protos
.

Comment: Не знаете путь – воспользуйтесь `find` или `locate`, если уж она при установке в `PATH` не добавилась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> утилиту proto c репозитория ubuntu

неясно, что за пакет вы установили. предположим, что это был пакет `protobuf-compiler`

> я не знаю путь к директиве protoc

вероятно, всё-таки не «к директиве», а «к программе». если установлен вышеупомянутый пакет, то в него входит программа `/usr/bin/protoc`. но указывать полный путь к ней вовсе не обязательно: так как каталог `/usr/bin` обычно входит в состав набора каталогов, содержащегося в переменной окружения `$PATH`, к ней можно обращаться просто по имени:

```
$ protoc <аргументы>
```

#### после правки вопроса

> я не знаю путь к директиве protos

вероятно, имеется ввиду опция `-Iпуть`. выдержка из `$ man protoc`:

> -IPATH, --proto_path=PATH
> Specify the directory in which to search for imports. May be specified multiple times; directories will be searched in order. If not given, the current working directory is used.

если вы не знаете, какие именно файлы могут понадобиться программе `protoc` для интерпретации вашего файла `habr.proto`, то попробуйте запустить её без этой опции. программа должна написать вам, какие файлы ей не удалось найти, тогда можно будет и указать путь(-и) к этим файлам.

найти файл по его имени можно, например, с помощью программы `find`:

```
$ find / -name имя.файла 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Я опечатался, я имел ввиду protos(один из аргументов), иными словами, какие аргументы нужно передать утилите, чтоб скомпилировать файл test.proto???

Comment: например, чтобы создать cpp-файлы с помощью [примера](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial), достаточно добавить ещё опцию `--cpp_out=каталог`. в качестве целевого каталога можно указать, например, текущий (`.`): `$ protoc --cpp_out=. test.proto`

Comment: @DenverToha, дополнил ответ.